Delphi QA audits are not selectable in a VCL project
I like to use the QA audits (to find some code smells) that are built-in to the Delphi IDE.
In a VCL project, most audits are not selectable. The only audits I can enable are the 'Basic' or 'Branches and Loops' category.
I am using Delphi 10.4. Are there any requirements to enable audits like "member is not used" or "unnecessary type cast"?



I have assumed that the two you can enable (same with me) are the only ones available in the Community/Professional editions.  But Embarcadero's feature matrix doesn't indicate that, so I don't know.

@PhilipJ.Rayment Thanks for the reply. I am using a Professional licence. The sales department only replied that it is not mentioned in the feature matrix.

I have a copy of the Alexandria feature matrix, and it does have an entry "Audits and metrics" which is available in all editions of Delphi.  But there is just that single entry, not separate entries for each audit option.
